# Google Co-ordinates for specific location in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, google-maps, radio-button

How do i Use the Google Co-ordinates for selected location.. I am using PHP and jQuery.
And [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8SAA6/) is my Fiddle...

```
<input type="radio" name="r"><label>New York</label>
<input type="radio" name="r"><label>Paris</label>
<input type="radio" name="r"><label>Los Angeles</label>    

Latitude   <input type="text"> 
Longitude  <input type="text">
```

Comment: Refere this http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

Comment: This is good. but how do i get Lat and Long of different locations ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This from [the google developer documentation for their geocoding api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding):

Geocoding is the process of converting addresses (like "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA") into geographic coordinates (like latitude 37.423021 and longitude -122.083739)

Is that what you need?